# Read-Only USB thumb as Linux boot encryption authentication

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

I would like to have a physical key to decrypt Linux machines at boot. This is just an idea and I would like to know if there are already projects or established methods to achieve this. Let me explain better. 
I would like to have an usb device full of random data no partition, then make this thumb read only. First of all: is this possible? Is there some kind of bit that would prevent data write? Something like the SD physical lock, just not physical.
Then: what encryption with Linux? I would like to have a pre-boot authentication with simmetrical encryption.. With the hash of the random data key as password.

And a last question: are there some kind of ASIC usb devices to speedup encryption?

Thank you all.

Comment: I once had an USB key with a physical write lock switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a LUKS volume that relies on a keyfile, rather than on some user input.

There's a guide here, but I've not followed it myself.  It seems quite sound though, from a quick read through.

[LUKS USB key unlock](http://www.gaztronics.net/howtos/luks.php)

Consider also the pros and cons of doing this.  A pro is that your key can be longer than you could comfortably remember, but a con is that it's physical, and easily stolen.  If you're looking for a higher level of security, I expect it's possible to require *both* a keyfile and passphrase (at the same time, that gives you more stuff to forget/lose).

Weigh up your options before doing something like this.